# Why does asort work with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, sorting

Apologies if this is a really basic question. I've inadvertently discovered that [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) appears to work with multidimensional arrays:

**Sample PHP**

```
$animals = array(
  1 => array('name' => 'Zebra'),
  2 => array('name' => 'Fox'),
  3 => array('name' => 'Rabbit'),
  4 => array('name' => 'Dog'),
  5 => array('name' => 'Cat')
);

asort($animals);
var_dump($animals);
```

**Output**

```
array
  5 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Cat' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Dog' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Fox' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Rabbit' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Zebra' (length=5)
```

**I'd like to know why this works?**

I thought [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) only sorted flat arrays, and to sort multidimensional arrays you needed to define a custom sort function. I can't find anything in the documentation that explains the above behaviour.

Comment: Thats a simple multi dimensionaly array, try with a larger one. array_multisort is for multi dimensioanl arrays

Comment: @user1281385: 1. there is no "simple" or "not simple" arrays in php 2. `array_multisort ` is not for multidimensional arrays

Comment: Are you sure ?? http://codepad.org/TC63qGFF It works with simple array too

Comment: @zerkms from the docs "array_multisort() can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions." so yes it it. and being simple by only having 1 dimension, its very easy to sort based on string value then

Comment: @user1281385: it's not for multi-dimensional arrays specifically. It can be used with **any** arrays.

Comment: @user1281385 even if I add another dimension to the array, it **still** works

Comment: @zerkms i was replying to his comment "multidimensional arrays you needed to define a custom sort function"

Comment: `sort()` behaves similar in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are compared in the lexicographical order by their values, so an array where the first element is "cat" is less than an array where the first element is "zebra". This is just a normal single dimension sort that happens to compare arrays to each other.

For example:

```
php > var_dump(array('a')< array('b'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(array('a')> array('b'));
bool(false)
```

Comment: Hm, any reference for that?

Comment: Found it http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - ctrl-f for "Transcription of standard array comparison"

Comment: Indeed, `Array with fewer members is smaller, if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2 then arrays are uncomparable, otherwise - compare value by value (see following example)`. On the other hand finding real case scenario for using such feature is completely another story.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept as soon as it will let me :p (Thanks also @zerkms)

Comment: Thanks @mpapec - it makes a lot of sense having read the transcription of standard array comparison. Obviously I'm not very good at finding documentation :p

Answer (score 3):

This is the transcription of [standard array comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
 (in PHP)

```
<?php
// Arrays are compared like this with standard comparison operators
function standard_array_compare($op1, $op2)
{
    if (count($op1) < count($op2)) {
        return -1; // $op1 < $op2
    } elseif (count($op1) > count($op2)) {
        return 1; // $op1 > $op2
    }
    foreach ($op1 as $key => $val) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $op2)) {
            return null; // uncomparable
        } elseif ($val < $op2[$key]) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($val > $op2[$key]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0; // $op1 == $op2
}
?>
```

That's coherent with your case

Answer (score 0):

PHP compares array according to number of elements, for example: arrays with one element will be compared together, and will be sorted at top first, then, PHP looks for similar arrays (based on number of elements) then compare them with each other for sorting, and so on, for example:

```
array(
a => array(z),
c => array(a,b),
d => array(d,r,3,4),
e => array(h,k,,p)
}
```

using asort, the result will be 
`a => array(z)` will be first element, because there is no other array with one element, therefore, it will be assigned at first place.

```
array(
c => array(x,b),
e => array(h,k,,p)
a => array(z),
d => array(d,r,3,4),
}
```