# Insert an array at position x of an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

We have an array of ranges in `$r`:

```
$r = array( array(3,5), array(36,54) );
```

We want to add a new range to our ranges:

```
$n = array(11, 19);
```

We also want `$r` to be sorted, so the new range should be inserted at position `1`. If we use `array_splice` the result would be having `11` and `19` added as two new elements:

```
array_splice($r, 1, 0, $n);
// output: array( array(3,5), 11, 19, array(36,54) )
```

How can we get the desired result as shown below?

```
// output: array( array(3,5), array(11,19), array(36,54) )
```

Comment: have you tried adding another dimension to $n?  $n=array(array(11,19)) and splicing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap array with new range in another array:

```
array_splice($r, 1, 0, array($n));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(19)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(36)
    [1]=>
    int(54)
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/316951)

Answer (score 2):

This may be easier that you think. Reading [array_splice's documentation](http://php.net/array_splice), you see that the `$replacement` parameter is an array and should contain all elements that should be inserted into the array.

So consider the following code:

```
array_splice($r, 1, 0, array(11, 19));
```

This does not insert `array(11, 19)` as one element into the array, but each `11` and `19` as two elements.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
array_splice($r, 1, 0, array(array(11, 19)));
```

Or, in your concrete example:

```
array_splice($r, 1, 0, array($n));
```

Alternatively, you could simply append and then completely re-sort the array (which might be not as efficient, but a bit easier for small data sets):

```
$r[] = $n;
usort($r, function($a, $b) { return $a[0] - $b[0]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting them to be in order of the first value in the range, then you could do the following.

```
$r = array( array(3,5), array(36,54));
$r[] = array(11,19);
print_r($r);
sort($r);
print_r($r);
```

results:

Not sorted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 54
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 19
        )

)
```

Sorted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 54
        )

)
```

[view this answer to another question that explains why sort() works on multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614258/4815044)